# The Pitcairn Islands (pop. 50) are on the UN list of non-self governing nations. Does the UN have a proposal for the ultimate status of that "nation"?

Tags: united-kingdom, united-nations

The Pitcairns Islands are listed on the [UN list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_list_of_non-self-governing_territories#Current_entries) of non-self governing territories. Unlike all the other entries which might theoretically function as an independent state, the Pitcairn Islands have a population of 50 people, and it doesn't seem feasible for them to survive as an independent nation, if the UK were to proclaim them as such.

Did the UN publish any recommendations as to what the future of the Pitcairn Islands should look like? Do they actually envision them to be fully independent or suggest some other resolution?

Comment: No one doubts that it is a non-self-governing territory. The question is whether this implies that an alternative solution is necessary under the general rule of decolonialism.

Comment: @ohwilleke it seems like the UN wants the UK to do *something* about the Pitcairn islands. It's unclear what that action is exactly.

Comment: I upvoted, but maybe you should edit the title to be more in line with body. It's not clear that being on that list means the UN wants them fully independent.

Comment: Well, the UN's approach to these territories has always been a bit confusing. They apparently don't care whether a territory actually lacks representation in a national government (Puerto Rico and Hong Kong are fine, for instance, while some French overseas departments with full voting rights have not been). They want to get independence for countries that mostly oppose it, but the UN has always allowed voluntary mergers between independent states, so it is unclear how this could be maintained.

Comment: [FYI they had some criminal cases that definitely benefited from outside intervention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2004_Pitcairn_Islands_sexual_assault_trial).  Colonialism-wise, unlike most other such cases, Pitcairn islanders are not descendents of expropriated natives.  So I find this UN status rather odd.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica right, I can understand all the other entries but... *Pitcairn Island*?! Seems completely bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they don't exactly say. A/RES/76/99 which is the latest I could find is full of the usual verbiage/platitudes that there's no alternative to self-determination [that should be achieved by 2030], but also says

> Noting with serious concern that the Territory last participated in the activities of the Special Committee in 2004,
>
> Taking into account the unique character of Pitcairn in terms of population, area and access,
>
> [...]

Their recommendations (too verbose to quote fully) are for Pitcairn to resume participation in that committee and for the administering Power to "promote the economic and social development and to preserve the cultural identity of the Territory", which one might say are actually contradictory goals to a good extent.